# meteor collections field search

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, meteor

I grab the currently selected mongo document using 'this' inside of a Template.alerts.events function. I then want to check to see if the current document (this) contains a specific field. To be precise, I want to see if it contains the userId which I store there myself previously.

```
doc {
    field1: 'a'

    myfield: {
        userId1: timestamp
        userId2: timestamp
        ...
    }

}
```

I basically want to see if the current user's userId is in the userId fields of myfield.

I have tried:

```
var x = this.userId
if(this.myfield.x) {
    //do something
}
```

and I'm wondering whether it is because I need to wrap userId in a string or something, but I can't get the condition to evaluate. I have also tried using object.hasOwnProperty which also didn't work. How can I do this in a non query way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to see if 'x' is a field in the object `this.myField`. If so, you have to do something like this: `if (this.myfield[this.userId])`. If you're trying to compare `x` and `this.myfield`, then you need to do `if (this.userid == this.myfield)`

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work. I'm right now using this.myField[this.userId]  because I just want to see if this field exists. Do I have to search the fields or something?